# Should I put an article before "House E"?

Tags: grammar

When you say "house 25", you don't add "the". Does the zero article apply to the use of the alphabet: house e?

Comment: First, please, more context or explanation of what you don't understand. As such, "House 25" I would call a building desgnation, so like an address does not have any article. On the other hand, "house 25" depends on what that is.

Comment: There would be no difference; neither one calls for an article.   By the way, are  "House 25" and "House E" addresses?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Thanks for your help. It doesn't have to be addresses but that way would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an ordinal number, or letter functioning as such a number, follows a noun, the article typically should not be used.  I think this is because really what is happening is that the number is actually functioning as a noun and the preceding word is technically a modifier - because it's possible to omit the preceding word.

> Right now I'm on step 16 (or it could be "Right now I'm on 16" if the listener knew you were working off a list of steps)
>
> I've parked in space 'F' (again, "I've parked in 'E'" will work, if the listener knew you were trying to find a parking spot)

So, for:

> I'm looking for house 'E'.

don't use the article.

Of course, with something like:

> I'm looking for the 3rd house.

you would use it.